# How to toggle display:none, display:block

Tags: jquery, html, css

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  ('.button').click(function() {
    let item = $(this).closest('item');
    if (item.css.('display') === 'none') {
      item.show();
      item.css('display', 'block');
    } else if (item.css.('display') === 'block') {
      item.hide();
      item.css('display', 'none');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.item {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button class="button">Click</button>
  <div class="front">front page</div>
  <div class="item">
    This is a paragraph with little content. This is another small paragraph.
  </div>
</div>
```

Aim is to hide and show the current div on button click. i have the same container with the same class names.  if i use simply toggle button, upon clicking the button, every other containers are toggled. In this case, only current container must show and hide. The class container's first div child is initally displayed and the second div child is hidden/ display:none. upon button click, the second div child is displayed, the display:none is change to display:block.  Code here seems not working.

Comment: There's various issues with your code...`.closest('')` only searches parent nodes so it actually won't return anything. Additionally your `closest('.item')` is missing the `.` to denote that it's the class which it's looking for.

Comment: also you're missing the function name (`$`) of one of your jquery calls...

Comment: Since you're using jQuery, you might want to just use the method `toggle()` https://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: You don't need both `hide/show` and `css`. What do you think `hide` and `show` do other that change the CSS?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [.siblings()](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/)

> Given a jQuery object that represents a set of DOM elements, the
>   .siblings() method allows us to search through the siblings of these
>   elements in the DOM tree and construct a new jQuery object from the
>   matching elements.

***Working snippet:-***

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.button').click(function() {
    $(this).siblings(".item").toggle();
  });
});
```

```css
.item {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <button class="button">Click</button>
  <div class="front">front page</div>
  <div class="item">
    This is a paragraph with little content. This is another small paragraph.
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `parent()` to find current button click element and then find `.item` class in that container and simply use `fadeToggle()` to *hide* and *show* element as below.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.button').click(function(){
        $(this).parent().find(".item").fadeToggle();
    });
});
```

```css
.item{display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container"> 
    <button class="button">Click</button>
    <div class="front">front page</div> 
    <div class="item">
        This is a paragraph with little content.
        This is another small paragraph.
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".button").click(function(){
        $(".front").toggle();
        $(".item").toggle();
    });
});
</script>
<style type="text/css">
    .item{display: none;}
</style>
<button class="button">Click</button> 
<div class="front">front page</div> 
<div class="item">
    This is a paragraph with little content.
    This is another small paragraph.
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `$(this).parent().find(":not(.button)")`, so as to toggle everything inside the container other than the button:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.button').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().find(":not(.button)").toggle();
  });
});
```

```css
.front,
.item {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <button class="button">Click</button>
  <div class="front">front page</div>
  <div class="item">
    This is a paragraph with little content. This is another small paragraph.
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just trigger the `.toggle()`, `.slideToggle()`, or `.fadeToggle()` fuctions instead of checking visibility, and I'd use the `.siblings('.item').first()` to find the appropriate element based on your html and original js code.

```js
$('.button').click(function() {
  let item = $(this).siblings('.item').first();
  item.slideToggle();
});
```

```css
.item {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <button class="button">Click</button>
  <div class="front">front page</div>
  <div class="item hidden">
    This is a paragraph with little content. This is another small paragraph.
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has some errors like `css.("display")` is not any function like in JQuery.

You can use any of this way to solve your problem,

```
$(function(){

$('.button').on("click",function(){

var item = $(this).next("div").next('.item'); // For second next
 //var item = $(this).siblings('.item'); // By siblings() function
//var item = $(this).next().closest('.item'); // By siblings() function
item.toggle();
});

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **toggle**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("div.item").toggle(1000);
    });
});
</script>
<style>.item {
  display: none;
 }</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container"> 
   
<button>Hide</button>
    <div class="front">front page</div> 
    <div class="item">
        This is a paragraph with little content.
        This is another small paragraph.
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery detox, plain Javascript rocks.

```js
document.querySelector('button.button').onclick = function() {
    let item = document.querySelector('div.item');
    (getComputedStyle(item).display === 'none') ? item.style.display = 'block' : item.style.display = 'none';
}
```

```css
.item { display: none }
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <button class="button">Click</button>
    <div class="front">front page</div>
    <div class="item">This is a paragraph with little content. This is another small paragraph.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It seems this something no one asked for, the question is tagged `jquery`.

Answer (score -1):

you can toggle junk with the jquery toggle method.

```js
setInterval(()=>$("h1").toggle(), 50);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>hello</h1>
```